# Dynamic segment URL in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to change my URL from

> www.mydomain.com/data/2

to

> www.mydomain.com/name-data

i try to config in my `routes.php` like this

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'data/$1';
$route['login-resgistration'] = 'f/login/index';
```

but when I type on address bar

> www.mydomain.com/login-registration

or

> www.mydomain.com/anotherword

it returns to data controller.

Comment: in CI when you set routes and if instead of `http://my,website.com/MyController/MyFuction/param1/param2` you want to create a route like `http://my.website.com/page1-param1-param2` the way to set it is in `../config/routes.php  ->   $route["page1-(:any)-(:any)"] = "MyController/MyFuction/$1/$2"`

Comment: But first check for **typos** you wrote **resgistration** maybe in your code or your URL you typed **registration**

Comment: I don't do typos it's still return to DataController

Comment: Care to explain what **f** means in `f/login/index` and by the way the index funcion is accessed automatically, for example: `MyController/index -> $route["some-name"] = "MyController";`

Comment: it's just example, when i declare to another function like `$route['my-account'] = 'f/login/myaccount'` it's still return to data controller

Comment: Seems that is going to the default controller, it means that `f/login/myccount` try with `$route['my-account'] = 'login/myaccount'` on the class/function you are reffering the format has to be like that `Class/Function/param1/param2/.../paramN` hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare all the routes before the main data controller route.

```
$route['login-resgistration'] = 'f/login/index';
$route['my-account'] = 'f/login/myaccount';
$route['(.*)'] = 'data/$1';
```

Hope this will work.